# filter in specific multiple expressions angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to search in column name or number only, currently i'm only searching in column name.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="test.name" placeholder="start typing..">
```

my expressions,

```
  <tr ng-repeat="x in names | filter:test | limitTo:totalDisplayed">
                            <td>{{ x.name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ x.number}}</td>
                            <td>{{ x.city }}</td>
                            <td>{{ x.country }}</td> 
                        </tr>
```

Comment: What does this mean more specifically? Toggle which column you search or match either column? If it is the latter you will need a custom filter

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom filter to accomplish this.

html

```
<input type="text" ng-model="test.name" placeholder="start typing..">
        <tr ng-repeat="x in names | myFilter: test">
                       <td>{{ x.name }}</td>
                       <td>{{ x.number}}</td>
                       <td>{{ x.city }}</td>
                       <td>{{ x.country }}</td> 
                   </tr>
```

js filter

```
angular.module('myApp').filter('myFilter', function () {
      return function (list, input) {

    //input is test object and list is your current array you want to return a filtered array
    var myArray = [];
    list.forEach(function(o, i){
        if(o.name.indexOf(input.name) > -1 || o.number.indexOf(input.name) > -1 )
            myArray.push(o);
    });

    return myArray
};
});
```